# UIPickerView look-alike on Android

Tags: iphone, android, custom-view

[image]

Hi, I have seen the above control in a few Android applications. I know it is not native to Android, what is the name of the control and how do I implement it in Android? Could it be done using a ListView including the behavior?

Comment: Even i'm looking for answer to same ! how-to ....

Comment: you can use an alert dialog box with list view in it

Comment: Why havent I seen this on Android apps....?

Comment: @Asad Khan, Check Bubble Blast 2! I just got a logic behind it. They have used a ListView.

Comment: Check the following link http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ to find a custom view that imitates the UI Picker View.

Comment: While it's "cool" per se, I'd rather have something native to the Android platform in 99% of all cases - for usability and also maintainability. You don't wanna go back to update flaws and stuff in that android wheel source code.

Comment: @Jonny, I second it as well. I'd prefer to use components specific to their platforms these days and convince my clients to do the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use NumberPicker widget with using displayed value to be strings you want picker to show.

```
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
    picker.setMaxValue(5);
    String[] strs = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
    picker.setDisplayedValues(strs);
    picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
```

Comment: I just forgot that you still might not be able to use images in that.

Answer (score 6):

On iPhone it's called `UIPickerView`. I wouldn't recommend to exactly immitate its look, because it won't harmonize with the look of the other GUI widgets of android, which will result in some kind of a "cheap" look'n'feel for the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can make custom Spinners for Android, it just takes some work. I suggest taking a look at this tutorial to see how to create the custom view the user sees before bringing up the Spinner: http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57.

As for the actual view that is shown...you'll want to look into making a custom Adapter object that you can pass into the Spinner object. For this, I would probably look in to expanding on one of the Adapters Google has provided or even using one as an example. For more on Adapters you can look at the Google SDK for Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html.

I do agree with Dominik though...you should stay with the Android look and feel to keep consistency.

Comment: what would be the best decision if I am porting an iPhone Application and my client wants the same look and feel?

Comment: Well, it is up to the client as to what they actually want in the end but you could try explaining to them that Android is a different platform with different user interface guidelines and that users are looking for applications that match the Android look and feel. Even if the interface does not look the exact same between the iPhone and an Android device, as long as the same functionality is there, the user shouldn't care or notice one way or another. I think it would be best to stick with the Android UI. Plus, it will save you time and effort and let you deliver something sooner.

Comment: You might find this useful for outlining some of Android's UI patterns: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html